# ScrewTurn Wiki Internal Linking?

Tags: screwturn

I am trying to make an internal link that will link to a section of the page the user is on. I have looked around but, I can't find anything. Their forums were shutdown a while ago so it doesn't really help.

Any help is appreciate it

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are little paragraph symbols next to each section name on the destination page. Click on it and look in the address bar to find out what name you need to add to the link after a hash mark. Your link will end up looking like this `[PageName#Section_1]`

Answer (score 1):

An anchor to a location in the same page is created as such:

```
[anchor|#ManConfig]
```

The link back to the anchor is created as such:

```
[#ManConfig|Manually Configure Your Connection]
```

Where the name of the anchor in this example is "ManConfig"